# Mac Java 11 vs Java 8 dylib dlopen error: Cannot load libzstd.1.dylib

Tags: java, java-8, java-native-interface, java-11, dylib

I have a libhadoopzstd.dylib that is part of a JNI Hadoop ZSTD implementation.

`libhadoopzstd.dylib` contains dlopen calls to a second dylib - `libzstd.1.dylib` - assumed to be available locally.

Everything works fine on Java 8 (AdoptOpenJdk 1.8.0.211). Running the same code with the Java 11  (AdoptOpenJdk 11.0.8) compiler and the Java 11 Runtime results in the following error:

```
Error loading zstandard native libraries: java.lang.InternalError: Cannot load libzstd.1.dylib (dlopen(libzstd.1.dylib, 9): image not found)!
```

I've confirmed that `libzstd.1.dylib` is present in `/usr/local/lib`. I've also tried to explicitly point `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `java.system.path` to the libzstd dylib when running the java program.

I've inserted print statements in the original C code, and recompiled the `libhadoopzstd.dylib` to try and figure out what paths `dlopen` is searching for `dylib` files in. Oddly enough, the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` and `JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH` all show up as `null` from within `libhadoopzstd.dylib`.

Since the only difference is the Java version, I think Java 11 is doing something different with paths that Java 8 is not. Does anyone know whether this is true?

Furthermore, anyone know what paths `dlopen` searches when run from within the JVM? And how one can confirm this?

Comment: You can set some variables to debug dyld (the macos dynamic linker) see [this page](https://lowlevelbits.org/debugging-dyld/) and [`man dyld`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/dyld/). If you cannot figure it out, edit your question with relevant output from your investigations.